# Illustrator: how to cut and delete a group of elements

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have the following group of elements created using `Blend`/`Make` option in Illustrator. Is there any possibility to delete the selected left part before the guideline?

I've tried eraser tool but is not so precise, I can't use it as a rectangle/delete tool.

[View post on imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngwny.jpg)[image]

Comment: Expand then one of the various Pathfinder options.

Comment: @CAI thanks; I used Object menu/Expand option, selected the rectangle,  selected using shift the lines and tried the pathfinder options but I something went wrong ... not so sure why. I obtain only one line cutted ... not all. (!?)

Comment: Check Elbasan's answer. Creating a compound path will get around that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Select all of them and then **right click > Make Compound Path**

[image: right click > Make Compound Path]

Then draw a shape over the area *(it needs to be on top of the other shape)* you want to remove, then select all the shapes and in Pathfinder select "Minus front"

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Make Compound Path, check! but when I try to use the "Minus front" I get "the filter produce no result" message. It could be related to the tool I use for the select all operation?

Comment: Is the shape on top of the lines? And you should use the "Selection Tool" not the "Direct selection tool"

Comment: yes ... the shape on top of the lines. I noticed something. My selection it doesn't look like yours... it's not rectangle around the line it looks like a path selection (simple line) why God knows...remember my lines are created using Blend/Make are not separate lines ... could this be a problem?

Comment: this is how they look after Expand option top view and then, after Compound... http://imgur.com/a/TRzNq

Comment: Aha, then select all the lines, go to Object > Path > Outline stroke
After that you need to go to each line and ungroup it, then make the use "Make Compound Path"

Comment: it works thanks! Selection tool, select all, Object/Expand: Object, Fill, Stroke, Object/Path/Outline stroke, Group selection tool/ select all, Object/Compound Path/ Make, fill with color, then rectangle tool draw rectangle over the lines, selection tool, select all, Minus front and bam! thank you for your support.

Comment: I have a single concern, transforming the path in outline stroke will influence somehow the quality of the vectors? thanks

Comment: Not really, as it is still a vector, but now it is a shape instead of a line

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: unfortunately I can't up vote ...yet! but as soon as I'll be able to do that, I'll come back and I'll vote ur answer :)

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a group of objects that are not the same color(where a compound path won't work?). Basically I just want a clipping mask, but instead of cropping everything in view, I want it to actually cut the objects.